# Unique id of an android activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to get an unique id of an android activity instance. I'd like to take the string which the activitymanager writes in the log (for example: ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{**450495a0** ...}), but I don't know how to get it.

Does someone know how I can get this string? Or is there another unique id for each activity instance?

Comment: Define domain for uniqueness.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: Unique where? Unique in the device? Unique in the Earth? Unique in the universe?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you can use Activity's hashCode.

Comment: It would be nice to get the string of the activitymanager, but the hashcode would of course do the job too. If I'm not able to get this specific string, I would take the hashcode, but the other sting will make debugging easier for me.

Answer (score 6):

As correctly pointed out in the other answer, activities can be recreated by the OS, so using `Activity.hashCode()` is not a reliable solution. Moreover, the whole app process can be recreated (after permission change, for example), which means any runtime/non-persisted ID cannot be trusted. A correct solution is manually generate a unique ID during `onCreate(Bundle)` (or read it from `savedInstanceState`, if exists) and save it during `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`.

Another problem is generating truly unique ID. The simplest and most reliable solution is too keep a static counter, but since app process may die, it requires a little more care.

To bring boilerplate code to a minimum, I've put together a specialized class:

```
public class ActivityUUID {

    private static final String INSTANCE_DATA_ID = "BwsKCwYBDg8GAQ4LBAgAAA"; // NOTE Any globally unique ID
    private static final String UUID_NODE_ID = "a";
    private static final long INVALID_UUID = 0;

    private static long _lastActivityUUID = INVALID_UUID; // NOTE All activity callbacks are guaranteed to be made from UI thread, so no synchronization is required
    private static SharedPreferences _persistentData;

    private final long _uuid;

    public ActivityUUID(Context context, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        _uuid = readUUID(context, savedInstanceState);
    }

    public long get() {
        return _uuid;
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.putLong(INSTANCE_DATA_ID, _uuid);
    }

    private static long readUUID(Context context, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        long result = (savedInstanceState != null) ? savedInstanceState.getLong(INSTANCE_DATA_ID, INVALID_UUID) : INVALID_UUID;
        return (result != INVALID_UUID) ? result : generateUUID(context);
    }

    private static long generateUUID(Context context) {
        if (_persistentData == null) {
            _persistentData = context.getSharedPreferences(INSTANCE_DATA_ID, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            _lastActivityUUID = _persistentData.getLong(UUID_NODE_ID, INVALID_UUID);
        }

        long result = ++_lastActivityUUID;
        if (result != INVALID_UUID) {
            _persistentData.edit().putLong(UUID_NODE_ID, result).apply();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("You have somehow managed to create a total of 9223372036854775807 activities during lifetime of your app! =)");
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Usage is pretty simple:

```
private ActivityUUID _activityUUID;

@Override
public final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    _activityUUID = new ActivityUUID(this, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    _activityUUID.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

// ...somewhere else in the code
long activityUUID = _activityUUID.get();
```

Answer (score 2):

every where in your project :

```
    MainActivity.class.hashCode();
```

in Activity

```
    this.hashCode();
```

You can even get `hashCode` from context

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a bit outdated, but i needed this for some reasons.

It is NOT a good idea to use the hashCode method of the activity, if you want to keep it for longer. As we all know, Activities can be cleaned up by the Operating System. This means, that when they get recreated, they probably have a different hashCode than the instance before. A solution for this (if you want to stay with an integer as id) could be the getIntent().hashCode()

Comment: OP needs an unique id per activity instance, so I don't see why using hashCode is bad.

Answer (score 1):

`hashCode()` method in `Activity`，it returns an unique id of an android activity instance，but `getTaskId()` can not return unique value