# Identifying android screen uniquely

Tags: android

I am looking for a way to create a unique identifier for an Android screen. By Android screen I mean a screen of any application of a mobile with Android OS. Approaches that I already tried:

By using "**adb shell dumpsys activity activities**" I can get the activity name. With "**adb shell dumpsys activity package-name**" I can get the fragment name.

I tried then to create an ID based on the activity plus the fragment but I found out that sometimes different screens use the same activity and fragment.

Then I added to the ID the first text that appear on the screen. I can get this text by using "**uiautomator dump**". But again there different screens with the same activity, fragment and first text. If I get also the second text I can solve the problem for some cases but it will afect negatively others.

If I compare the UI dump only I will have mistakes when the same screen is in a different state (e. g. Switchs ON or OFF).

The final purpose of this question is to know when I'm revisiting a screen.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Usually you would use Activity's hashCode... Activity1.class.hashCode(); but your explanation is misleading...
 What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Probable Duplication: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102967/unique-id-of-an-android-activity

Comment: As I said, two different screens can use the same activity. For example in Android O we have:
**Screen 1:** Settings > Sounds and vibration > Ringtone;    
**Screen 2:** Settings > Sounds and vibration > Notification sounds;    

The activity for both of these screens is the same: **com.android.providers.media/.RingtonePickerActivity**
In this case, only by the name of the activity I cannot say in which screen I am.

What I want to achieve at the end is to know when I am revisiting a screen